# How to access data sent from HttpWebRequest Stream via window.location.href in Java Script

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, web-services

I am relatively new to web programming.
I have a windows form trying to communicate with a web service through ajax and java scripts.
My form has below code,

```
        string sURL = <<URL>>;
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) HttpWebRequest.Create(sURL);

        //Modify request properties
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
        request.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;

        string sRequestData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new GetSessionInfo() { UserName = "xxxxxx", Database = "xxxxxx", Module = "xxxxxx" }.ToString());

        StreamWriter sWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());
        sWriter.Write(sRequestData);
        sWriter.Close();

        try
        {
            //Extract the response
            HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
            if (response == null)
                return false;

            StreamReader responcestream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            string ResponseData = responcestream.ReadToEnd();
            responcestream.Close();
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
```

My index.html file looks like below

```
        function Session()
        {   
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/ProcessRequestFromEasyOrder",
                data : JSON.stringify({ user:"****", Database:"****", module:"****"}),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "application/json",
                async: true,
                cache: false,
                cors: true,
                success:function(data){
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        }
```

At the moment I am able to call web service methods by hard coding parameters through browser. However when I try to do it via my windows form it always return me (405)Method Not Allowed.
Can someone please help me answer following questions,

- Can this be achieve? if so can you provide an example which achieve
  this?
- Is it due to an issue with web service settings? if so how do
  I get it fixed?
- Any alternative ways to do this? an example would
  be great

I am on .NET 4.5
Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Nothing is clear from your question. You said Windows Form and there isn't any code given for it

Comment: Sorry for the confusion the top code block is extracted from the button click event code in windows form. Full code is too big and confusing to put in.

Comment: 405 simply means POST/GET error. And if the services are developed by you, then simply add web reference to your WinForm application and use the proxy class generated by add reference.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but we can't simply add a web reference in this case. Web Service was developed on .NET framework 4.5 whereas the UI project on .NET framework 4.0. That is why we are sort of trying to remotely access the form.

Comment: if you are using basicHttpBinding then you can add reference even when the service is developed in version later than your client project